# Geofences Not Triggered By Walking Through Them

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

When a user terminates the app, I create a geofence around the user's last location, so that I can be notified when the user leaves that location.

```
CLRegion *workingGeoFence = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lastLocation.coordinate.longitude, lastLocation.coordinate.latitude) radius:80.4672 identifier:@"centered"];


workingGeoFence.notifyOnExit = YES;
workingGeoFence.notifyOnEntry = NO;

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:workingGeoFence];
```

**I'm calling the above method in response to this notification:**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterTerminatedMode) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```

I then wait a few minutes, and walk directly out of the geofence, through the boundary and continue on straight... the geofence is never triggered.

This is for GPS only devices, FYI.

Since the geofence is being created in response to `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`, `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:` never has a chance to be called before the app terminates. But right after calling `startMonitoringForRegion:`, the geofence does appear in the `monitoredRegions` property.

Using always authorization, and successfully gathering locations in both foreground and background modes.

Might this have something to do with it?...

> "Region events may not happen immediately after a region boundary is crossed. To prevent spurious notifications, iOS doesn’t deliver region notifications until certain threshold conditions are met. Specifically, the user’s location must cross the region boundary, move away from the boundary by a minimum distance, and remain at that minimum distance for at least 20 seconds before the notifications are reported."

**More Failed Tests**

[image: concentric geofences]
I activated notify on entry and exit, then created concentric geofences (see image. I walked through each one, and once or twice stopped for a minute then proceeded on.

Then walked about a mile away, came back and walked into each one, back to the center.... and nothing. Note even a single trigger on entry or exit.

I just don't understand how these activities could not be covered under a geofence implementation..

I tried this with wifi on/off.

I also tried opening another app that gathers a GPS location upon boot. And still nothing triggered. I thought Apple shared these precise locations amongst all apps?

My guess is that they ONLY use a change of cell ID?

Not sure what else to possibly try.

Comment: I would think it would make more sense to define a region at the current user location and wait for the region exit. With your current approach the user probably isn't remaining in the geofences region long enough. The term "geofence" is a little misleading. It isn't a like a tripwire that is triggered when you cross it. It is a region that you are either in or out of

Comment: funny enough, that crossed my mind last night! I was going to test it today. Definitely feels like a better solution

Comment: I just tested it. Created the fence (and it shows at the top of my phone the little outline, signifying there is a geofence being monitored). Waited maybe 30 seconds, then I walked from the center, directly out, through the boundary.... and nothing again...

Comment: not sure whether this matters but, when creating the geofence via `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification `.. `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion: ` never has a chance to be called before the app terminates. But right after calling `startMonitoringForRegion:`, the geofence does appear in the `monitoredRegions` property

Comment: Did you get the notification that you were *in* the region before you exited? Have you called `requestState` for your region and implemented the `didDetermineState` delegate method ?

Comment: Also, why are you doing this on application termination?  How are you terminating the app? Normally apps are just suspended and not terminated.

Comment: you don't get the`didEnterRegion:` call when you create a geofence you're already in. I tested this in the foreground to make sure.

Comment: And I'm getting 0 didEnter or didExit notifications. Never a single one. Mind you I've only been testing this around my house in the suburbs. Maybe in a city it would be different... but it still should work. I haven't implemented `requestState ` or  `didDetermineState `

Comment: terminating the app by the app switcher. But it 100% should and does work this way. It says explicitly in the apple documentation that it wakes up terminated apps for region monitoring events. .... And I'm doing it this way so that I can know when a user leaves the location he/she is at, and most people kill their apps this way (thinking it saves battery) (FYI i updated the question with some updated tests)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142990/discussion-between-paulw11-and-gukki5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order is (lat, lon) NOT (lon, lat)!!!!!!